# How do I program a CGI script to execute a remote script over ssh and display data from the remote execution?

Tags: perl, apache, ssh, cgi, ssh-keys

I have this particular case where I have to place the HTML pages and CGI scripts on ServerA and the CGI scripts will have to invoke Perl scripts on ServerB which will fetch data from a DB and the HTML pages on ServerA are to display the data.

I am successful at remotely triggering the perl script but am unable to decide what the best way is to get the data from ServerB back to ServerA and have it displayed with this architecture?

I considered the following:
ServerB exports data to a flatfile which is transferred back using scp to ServerA. The scp can be configured in the perl file on serverB.

**Question1:** How do I get the CGI on ServerA to wait until ServerB returns data. How do I handle error cases where data is not returned or when input parameters passed to ServerB ae incorrect?

**Question2:** Is there a better way to program around this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd be tempted to use [DBD::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aProxy) from ServerA with the proxy on ServerB, and get the data "directly" - allowing you to manipulate it in your CGI script.  Of course, this assumes the data you need comes back quickly enough not to time anything out.

Answer (score 2):

Your script should initiate the other process and exit. The other process should leave output in a file. You'll need to set up a way for the user to see the results when the other process concludes.

For inspiration, see Randal Schwartz's [Watching long processes through CGI](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html). These days, you could use [CGI::Session](http://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aSession).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this.  I hacked it out of some existing code I had in order to add comments.

It *should* work, with just minor modifications.

I hope it's enough to get you started.

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SCP qw(scp iscp);

$DEBUG = 0;

# Note: A public key exchange must first be created before this script will work
# without a password

$remHost = "machine.domain.sfx";
$remUser = "user_on_remote_machine";

# Name of file to send
$sndFile = "localfile.txt";

# scp is used to send the file to the remote host 
$scp = Net::SCP->new( $remHost, $remUser );
$scp->put( $sndFile ) or die $scp->{errstr};

$sndFile =~ s/.*\/(.*)/$1/;

# Use ssh to run a command remotely
$ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new( $remHost );
eval{ $ssh->login( $remUser, "" ); }
    or $msg = "Cannot connect to $remHost - Net::SSH error: ".join( "", $@ );

# Copy the file to another directory on the remote host
$cmd = "cp $sndFile /opt/tmp";

if( $DEBUG > 0 )
    { print STDERR "cmd = $cmd\n"; }

# Execute the command
eval{ ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd); };

if( $DEBUG > 0 )
{
    print STDERR "stderr = $stderr\n";
    if( $DEBUG > 1 )
        {   print STDERR "stdout = $stdout\n"; }
}

# Store the output of the ssh command in an array
@remArr = split( "\n", $stdout );
```

Comment: Have you considered web server timeouts for CGI scripts?

Comment: It looks like I might have been in too much of a hurry to answer - I didn't read your question completely.  I'm going to leave this here just in case.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response.
Figured out that the Perl on Server B outputs everything to the stream after the CGI from Server A invokes it with remote ssh command - I don't need that output in a  file but the operation runs as expected and I get all the Perl output that I intended to get in first place.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're forking the remote SSH command, hence the confusion about waiting for the remote command to finish. The following does what you want:

```
open(my $F, "-|", "ssh $REMOTE_HOST $REMOTE_COMMAND") || die $!;

while(<$F>) {
  do_something_with_data($_);
}
```